# SurfaceScrollBar won't respond to styling

Tags: wpf, xaml

The application I'm working on has a surfacelistbox whose scrollbar I'm trying to style, but for some reason nothing I'm doing is affecting it.

The style:

```
<Style TargetType="s:SurfaceScrollBar">
     <Setter Property="Template">
         <Setter.Value>
             <ControlTemplate TargetType="s:SurfaceScrollBar">
                 <Grid x:Name="Root">
                     <Track Margin="2,6,6,6"
                         Name="PART_Track"
                         Grid.Row="1"
                         IsDirectionReversed="true">
                         <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                             <s:SurfaceRepeatButton Command="ScrollBar.PageUpCommand" />
                         </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                         <Track.Thumb>
                             <s:SurfaceThumb Width="10"/>
                         </Track.Thumb>
                         <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                             <s:SurfaceRepeatButton Command="ScrollBar.PageDownCommand" />
                         </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                     </Track>
                 </Grid>
             </ControlTemplate>
         </Setter.Value>
     </Setter>
 </Style>
 <Style TargetType="s:SurfaceRepeatButton">
     <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
     <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
     <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
     <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
     <Setter Property="Template">
         <Setter.Value>
             <ControlTemplate TargetType="s:SurfaceRepeatButton">
                 <Border Background="Transparent"/>
             </ControlTemplate>
         </Setter.Value>
     </Setter>
 </Style>
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type s:SurfaceThumb}">
     <Setter Property="Template">
         <Setter.Value>
             <ControlTemplate TargetType="s:SurfaceThumb">
                 <Border CornerRadius="5"
                         Background="DimGray"/>
             </ControlTemplate>
         </Setter.Value>
     </Setter>
 </Style>
```

I've tried putting this style in app.xaml, in the window's resources, and in the resources of the listbox itself (`<s:SurfaceListBox.Resources>`), but nothing has any visual effect. However, if I change it to a regular listbox and change the style accordingly (surfaceScrollBar to ScrollBar, etc.), the style is applied fine no matter where I put it, but this breaks touch scrolling.

Am I doing something wrong with the style itself?

Comment: I suppose that you need to specify BasedOn attribute for you custom styles.

Comment: I don't think that's it, the style works just fine when it's applied to a regular listbox.